# Multithreading - Why does the following program behave this weirdly?

Tags: java, multithreading

The outline of the program:
 We have two threads (`t1` and `t2`) that write an integer value, then flush the written value to RAM.
Another thread (`t3`) checks whether the value coincidences with the one written by `t1`or `t2`, and if not, prints it.

```
public class Container
{
     int a;
     volatile boolean b;


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Container container = new Container();

        Thread t1 = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                for (;;)
                {
                    container.a = 409;
                    container.b ^= container.b;

                }
            }
        };

        Thread t2 = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                for (;;)
                {
                    container.a = 102;
                    container.b ^= container.b;
                }
            }
        };

        Thread t3 = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                for (;;)
                {
                    if (container.a != 409 && container.a != 102 )
                        System.out.println(container.a);
                }
            }
        };

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
    }
}
```

What I thought would happen: 
Since `a` isn't `volatile`, I thought `t3` would cache `a` and just never print anything.

What actually happens: 
For a second or so (no matter long you let `t3`sleep), it prints in rapid succession either 102 or 409. Then, printing stops (forever).

What exactly happens here?

Comment: As `System.out.println` is synchronized, it 'ruins' your expectations with respect to `a`. As to it stopping printing, that is a bit harder to say, maybe that is your console or IDE limiting the output.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`container.a` not being volatile doesn't mean it's mandatorily cached by `t3`. All it means is that there are no guarantees whether it will be or not.

The reason it is free to print any value is the time-of-check-to-time-of-use problem here:

```
if (container.a != 409 && container.a != 102 )
   System.out.println(container.a);
```

As for why this exact behaviour on the exact environment you tested it in, we can only guess. But my money would be on the theory that while the code is run as interpreted, it will go and read `container.a` every time, but once it's compiled to native code by Hotspot, the value is only loaded into a register once, and that's the end of it. You can verify this hypothesis by using the `-XX:+PrintCompilation` command line flag.

Comment: What held me up at first was how, having printed either 409 or 102, it could ever print a value again, since `a` is `int` and writes to it are atomic, so it would always have 409 or 102 in it from then on. The answer, of course, is that sometimes, when doing `container.a != 409 && container.a != 102`, the first read gets 102 and the second gets 409. :-)

Comment: Using the compiler flag, the printing ends around when `t3`'s run-method is being replaced by its corresponding compiled method, so your guess is most likely correct